# Heroku keys "Cannot read property 'run' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, heroku, ssh

I'm trying to use the Heroku cli "keys" functions to upload a ssh key to my account. Unfortunately I run into the following error whenever I try to use any of the keys methods.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'run' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\heroku\tmp\heroku-script-292666295:14:4)
at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:415:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:407:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
at startup (node.js:159:18)
at node.js:444:3
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems to be something new with the latest client update. I'm having the same problem today.

Comment: Same problem, and I'm just trying to do heroku open on the example node app.

Comment: I am also having this problem, but it's when trying to use `logs --tail`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After speaking with the Heroku support team we found that `heroku update` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It seems, Heroku command facing trouble finding right version of ruby so its throwing the error.

Uninstall **Heroku Toolbelt** through Windows "Control Panel\Programs and Features"  after successful uninstallation, delete C:\Program Files\Heroku folder as well.

And then reinstall **Heroku Toolbelt** and try to run the command. It should work.

Answer (score 2):

I removed this folder and all was well C:\Users\USERNAME.heroku.npm-cache

Answer (score 1):

Updating your package.json with the Node version you are using may fix this:

```
"engines": {
    "node": "6.0.0"
},
```

I was using version 6.0.0 locally, but Heroku was downloading version 5.11.1.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this error unstalling node.js from windows and removing the content of heroku folder(in appdata), after that typed on the propty: heroku --version. heroku said me to update git to other version, I updated it. then I run the command to generate a key again and worked perfectly. This worked to me.