# On any of my Heroku apps, several `heroku pg:` commands fail immediately with “Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined."

Tags: postgresql, heroku

(When I asked this previously, it was incorrectly flagged as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37048456/heroku-keys-cannot-read-property-run-of-undefined). They are not related.)

On any of my Heroku apps, several `heroku pg:` commands fail immediately with `Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined.`

For example:

```
$ heroku pg:push mydb DATABASE_URL -a $myapp
heroku-cli: Pushing mydb ---> postgresql-vertical-12345
 case 
------
 
(1 row)

 ▸    Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined
```

---

```
$ heroku pg:ps -a $myapp
 ?column? 
----------
(0 rows)

 ▸    Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined
```

This started within maybe the past two weeks. I have created/destroyed many apps, always with the same result. My goal is just to be able to push my local data. This error message doesn't exactly give me much in the way of next steps.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong (in which case, how do I fix it)?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue here and have created a support ticket, they responded by linking me to your github heroku/cli ticket.

I now see they have updated the docs on how to push a local db and recommend using s3 https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#import:

Generate a signed URL using the aws console:

`aws s3 presign s3://your-bucket-address/your-object`

Use the raw file URL in the pg:backups restore command:

`heroku pg:backups:restore '<SIGNED URL>' DATABASE_URL`

I haven't tried it yet but might be a workaround

Answer (score 0):

just had the same issue.. Updating the CLI fixed it for me. Just need to run `heroku update` ..